# Approximating lognormal sum pdf (in R)

Tags: r, lognormal-distribution

I have an application for which I need an approximation to the lognormal sum pdf for use as part of a likelihood function.  The lognormal sum distribution has no closed form, and there are a bunch of papers in signal processing journals about different approximations.  I have been using one of the simplest approximations (Fenton 1960), which involves replacing a sum of lognormals with a single lognormal with matching first and second moments.  This is pretty straightforward to code, but judging by the literature on the subject that has been written in the last 50 years, this may not be the best approximation for all applications.  I have no intuition for how to identify which approximations will lead to the best MLE estimates.

Does anyone know if 
(A) There is different approximation I should be using for a maximum likelihood application?
(B) There is existing R code for any of the more computationally intensive approximations?

Update: For some background on the problem, see [this review](http://www.soa.org/library/proceedings/arch/2009/arch-2009-iss1-dufresne.pdf)

Comment: Can you clarify just a touch? Is what you refer to as the "lognormal sum pdf" the density function of $Y = X_1 + \cdots + X_n$ where $X_n$ are iid lognormal with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$?

Comment: Yes, the pdf for the sum of N iid lognormal variates.

Comment: How large is $n$ in your application?

Comment: I am most interested in the cases where N is small, < 10 or so.  However, it would be very helpful if I could at least manage N up to 100 or so.

Comment: Moment matching a lognormal to this sounds on the surface like a strange idea. This is because the lognormal is *not* characterized by its moments. I will look here, but perhaps there is a way to turn the problem around a little. Let $f_0(x)$ be a "standard" ($\mu = 0$, $\sigma = 1$) lognormal density. For $b \in (-1,1)$, define $f_b(x) = f_0(x) (1 + b \sin(2\pi\log x))$. Then $f_b$ is a pdf and $f_0$ and $f_b$ have the same moments for *every* such $b$.

Comment: From the papers I have read on this, it looks like this approximation works well in the right tail, but less well elsewhere.  See [this review](http://www.soa.org/library/proceedings/arch/2009/arch-2009-iss1-dufresne.pdf) for some discussion on the history of the problem.

Comment: So, since you're summing iid copies of the same random variable, the lognormal sum distribution has moments that match the moments of the $f_b$. Generalizing further, we can take $\hat{f}(x) = f_0(x)(1 + \sum_k b_k \sin (k \pi \log x))$ and get the same moments as well as long as $\sum_i |b_i| \leq 1$. This may allow for some degrees of freedom to get an approximation while keeping **all** the moments equal.

Comment: It doesn't look like any of the methods in that review are quite what I've outlined above. That's not to say that it or some other paper hasn't looked at such a method. (I'd actually guess that it has been considered somewhere.)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will look into the approach you suggest.

Comment: I'll keep thinking about this. It's likely some others here will have some suggestions as well. If I come up with anything worthy of an actual "answer", I'll be sure and post it.

Comment: It seems like the lognormal distribution is 'product stable' (in analogy to the 'sum stable' class of distributions).  It seems that this property is shared by the sum of lognormals.  Perhaps there is some clever characterization of the product stable distributions (as there is of the sum stable class). Or maybe this is a dead end...

Answer (score 2):

To obtain a numerical version of distribution function for moderate $N$ (say a dozen of r.vs or less), a simple approach is to compute the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) of each LN density, form the product and then use inverse DFT. The same grid must be used for all densities and it must be designed with some care. The computation can be done quite easily in a R function. However, do not expect to reach the remarkable precision of the classical distributions functions in R.